# Is it possible to trigger a javascript alert when the website isn't secure?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple script that will trigger an alert when the website has no SSL protocol. Is it possible with javascript? Thanks

Comment: You can by inspecting if `location.href` begins with `http` or `https`.

Comment: yes try `if (location.href.includes('https:'))alert('site secure')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
if (location.href.includes('https:'))alert('site secure')

if (location.href.includes('http:'))alert('site not secure')
```

Comment: It's worth checking this against `http://example.com/#https:`, to see if it works like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [window location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). Essentially, if a url has "https" in it, means that it is secured. There is `window.location.protocol` that gives http or https which should help you determine